# Enable SQL server agent service by T-SQL script or PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, powershell

Can we enable/disable SQL server agent service by T-SQL script or PowerShell/cmd?

Comment: it's just a `net stop` in cmd, isn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without discounting anything stated in @**Shawn Melton**'s answer, there is one specific undocumented stored procedure that does this. It is `xp_servicecontrol`. Through it you can start, stop and check the service status of SQL Server Agent Service in TSQL.

If you want to start, stop or see the "Running/Stopping" status of the SQL Server Agent Service the Syntax is:

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'Querystate|Start|Stop',N'Service Name'
```

If you want to start the SQLServer Agent Service through TSQL then the syntax is as follows:

**To START SQL Server Agent**

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'START',N'SQLServerAGENT';
GO
```

**To STOP SQL Server Agent**

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'STOP',N'SQLServerAGENT';
GO
```

If you want to view the service status of the SQL Server Agent service then Syntax would be:

```
EXEC xp_servicecontrol N'querystate',N'SQLServerAGENT';
Go
```

After starting the SQL Server Agent service you shall get some message like this

> Service started
>
> Msg 22003 , level 1, state 0

And After Stopping the SQL Server Agent service you shall get a message like this

> Service Stopped
>
> Msg 22003 , level 1, state 0

**Note** :- `xp_servicecontrol` is an undocumented system stored procedure, so you will not get any support for it and moreover there is a chance of code changes or parameter changes, so be aware of this if you decide to use this.

For reference see [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2036/monitor-start-and-stop-sql-server-services-using-xpservicecontrol/) and [here](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/administration/xpservicecontrol/).

Comment: Great information on starting and stopping the service but OP asked about enabling/disabling which this cannot handle (more's the pity).

Answer (score 8):

It will depend on what version of PowerShell you are running, but this command can be used from at least 3.0 and up:

```
Set-Service SQLSERVERAGENT -StartupType Disabled
```

[image]

The alternative would be to use WMI, or you can use SQL Server WMI (microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.wmi namespace).

In T-SQL there is no mechanism native that lets you interact with the services. Outside of just using `xp_cmdshell` and calling PowerShell or cmd commands.